# Does this script perform the action every 10 milli second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell if the below script performs the click every 10 sec?

```
var time= setInterval(function(){
    var a= document.getElementsByClassName('product-flash-btn')[0].innerHTML;
    if(a == "Buy Now")
    { document.getElementsByClassName('product-flash-btn')[0].click()
    clearInterval(time); }
    else { console.log("Script Activated"); }
    },10);
```

Comment: No, it'll run every 10 milliseconds. For 10 seconds use `10000`

Comment: No the time is in millisecond So write `10000` for 10 second

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Headline question and body question are different. The answer could be "yes" or "no" depending on which question is being answered!

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a DOM [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 0):

No, it'll run every 10 milliseconds as setInterval takes time in milliseconds. For 10 seconds use `10000`.

Comment: Is it possible to run it at fraction of a milli second (is 0.0001 possible?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does but you will need to remove clearinterval  .

take a look at online example .

Time inteval value is milisecounds . 1000 = 1 sec

```js
var time= setInterval(function(){
    var a= document.getElementsByClassName('product-flash-btn')[0].innerHTML;
    if(a == "Buy Now")
    { 
    
    document.getElementsByClassName('product-flash-btn')[0].click()
    
      //clearInterval(time); 
    
    }
    else { console.log("Script Activated"); }
    },10000);
```

```html
<div class="product-flash-btn" onclick="alert('works')" >Buy Now</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to run it at fraction of a milli second (is 0.0001 possible?)

Comment: @Rishi why would you want to do that? You're going to freeze the browser, because it's not going to have any time left to do anything else, but run your function. If you want to freeze the browser all you have to do is say `while(true) {}`

Comment: Crazy but i have one time that case. In canvas 2d for iOS (ipad) i need to put 0,0001 for animation draw interval. You can but 1 milisec is so short interval ... Maybe you not need for < 1 .  Only for iOS i found usage ...

Comment: @Rishi just think about what you're asking there... 0.0001 of a milli-second?  so 0.0000001second?

Comment: @NikolaLukic for animation, you don't need anything > 50hz (20ms) as the human eye can't see any faster than that.

Comment: Yes but in any case time count depends on CPU . Interval are not same on dif computers ....

Comment: @freedomn-m I use timers for draw refresh . After 5.11 iOS thay change something in safari browser. Everything was slow ... I put 0,0001 for interval and guest what happened . canvas app get nice and fast draw job .

Comment: @NikolaLukic which has nothing to do with animations, but all to do with the inadequacies of iOS / safari.  Be definition, the interval in `setInterval` in javascript can't be less than 10ms.